# Websphere appending error to response

Tags: tomcat, servlets, struts2, websphere

Here scenario: I am working on a new functionality on an application using Struts2 and I added a new action to generate a CSV file. Everything works fine on my test system with Tomcat, but on the Quality system with a Websphere server, the file is ok but on the end, there is an extra line including

```
Error 500: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Response already committed.
```

So the thing is, file is generated and everything is perfect, but Tomcat does not append error, Websphere appends error.

So how can I avoid this?
Here the main process (lines that are important):

1- The action extends an org.apache.struts2.s1.Struts1Action which does the forwarding:

```
ActionForward forward = action.execute(mapping, actionForm, request, response);
```

2- Methods in the action are executed, with the following lines that generate the response:

```
response.setContentType("text/csv");
response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report_"
                + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + ".csv\"");
OutputStream outputStream = response.getOutputStream();
outputStream.write(result.toString().getBytes());
outputStream.flush();
outputStream.close();
```

3- The parent action finishes doing the thing. At some point, I get this exception, but it never worried us (we were already generating other type of excel reports(xls), but never got this problem with websphere appending the error to the response):

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException:getOutputStream() has already been called for this response
```

So what really wonders me is how to avoid websphere to append the error to the csv file... But of course the solution should be avoiding the error, but the thing is that this application has been running for 10 years and I shouldn't change things that already work, however any solutions to this error are welcome!!

Thank you very much guys!!

---Edit---

What I actually want to know, is how could I generate a response with a text file and still being able afterwards to do all the forwarding and stuff.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I actually found a solution to the problem, maybe not a solution by itself, but a workaround.

So the problem was that websphere was appending the error, as the `Response` content was just a String.

So what I did, was generating the response as a ByteArray, not as a String, this way websphere cannot append anything as simple text and the ByteStream is closed and safe.

```
        byte[] data = result.toString().getBytes();
        ByteArrayOutputStream outStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream(data.length);
        outStream.write(data, 0, data.length);
        response.setContentType("text/csv" + "; charset=UTF-8");
        response.setHeader("Expires", "0");
        response.setHeader("Cache-Control", "must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
        response.setHeader("Pragma", "public");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"report_"
                    + Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR) + ".csv\"");

        response.setContentLength(outStream.size());
        ServletOutputStream responseOutStream = response.getOutputStream();
        outStream.writeTo(responseOutStream);
        outStream.flush();
        outStream.close();
        responseOutStream.flush();
        responseOutStream.close();
```

Any edits, proposals or explanations are welcome if I did not explain it well enough!!

Answer (score 1):

Just trying to give you some ideas... Hope the following makes sense...

First of all, the cause of  `java.lang.IllegalStateException:getOutputStream()` according to this [source](http://www.java67.com/2016/03/javalangillegalstateexception-getOutputStream-has-already-been-called-for-this-response.html) is

> In short, this error comes when you call the include() or forward()
>   method after committing the response or by calling the
>   getOutputStream() on the response object

[Here](https://www.mkyong.com/struts/struts-download-file-from-website-example/) is an example of struts1 download implementation (as I understand it, you are using struts1 plugin for struts2). There we see the `execute` method ends with  `return null;`

So, may be, in the code that you have omitted from your post, there is some forwarding going on, that causes you the exception.

Comment: Indeed this could be the error. But I am already doing that, if I don't return null, it just does not work. But well the thing I guess is realising how can I correctly generate a response with a file and letting still do the forwarding and everything needed. The reason I am not posting much code is because I am not allowed to do it, so I am just posting the "general stuff" I could say. But thank you anyways. I will give it a look again.

Comment: @Carloshf What I actually was *worried* about was that, may be, you do not `return null` and do some `forwarding` instead. However without  the rest of  the code it's kind of difficult to understand what is going on wrong. Hope you'll find the solution soon...